# Github actions how to set multiple environment variables and reuse them for a docker image

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, cicd

Im building a simple CI/CD workflow with github actions. The workflow starts with running all unit tests. When the unit tests were successfull, a docker image gets build and uploaded to docker hub. I have a few environment variables that need to be set, in order run the tests and also to run the docker container.

Thats currently the only way I get it to work:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Linode k8s Cluster Workflow

env:
  REGISTRY: "abc"
  IMAGE_NAME: "defg"
  DO_POSTGRESQL_URL: ${{ secrets.DO_POSTGRESQL_URL }}
  DO_POSTGRESQL_USER: ${{ secrets.DO_POSTGRESQL_USER }}
  DO_POSTGRESQL_PASS: ${{ secrets.DO_POSTGRESQL_PASS }}
  # ... and more


# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    environment: test
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
     
        
      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 18
          distribution: temurin
          cache: gradle
        
      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2

      - name: Execute Gradle build
        run: ./gradlew build --scan
        
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2.1.0
        with:
          # Username used to log against the Docker registry
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
          # Password or personal access token used to log against the Docker registry
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          
      - name: Build and push Docker images
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.0.0
        with:
          context: .
          # because two jar files get generated (...-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar and ...-SNAPSHOT.jar) only ...-SNAPSHOT.jar is needed
          build-args: JAR_FILE=build/libs/*SNAPSHOT.jar, DO_POSTGRESQL_URL=$DO_POSTGRESQL_URL #,... and so on
          push: true
          tags: abc/defg:latest
          
          

      # Linode deployment here
```

But imagine im having multiple workflow files, then I have to add the environment variables on multiple different places. Is there a clever way to solve this problem. So that I only have to define the env variables once?

Comment: Did you evaluate using a self-hosted runner (with those variables stored), or eventually a reusable workflow?

Comment: Yes, I thought about a reusable workflow. Can you explain what you mean with a self-hosted runner?

Comment: Instead of using the Github runners (_e.g macos-latest, ubuntu-latest, windows-latest_), you could use a self hosted one (on AWS or another cloud platform) where you would already have set those env variables directly according to your context, for them to be used each time you would create/start an instance.

Comment: @JustAQuestion did you get any solution? if yes then please post your answer. i have many env values so is there any way i can read all at once during deployment process? i tried Azure App Service Settings but it's not working on server (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-app-service-settings)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to create a .env file in the workflow itself filled with content of github secret.

```bash
      - name: Set environment variables from secrets and create .env file
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.ENV_FILE }}" > .env
          ls -a
```